# Тахометр на arduino

Tags: arduino

Добрый день. На первичном валу катера приклеил 2 магнита, установил датчик холла. Данные с датчика холла поступают на Arduino due. Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
#include <DueTimer.h>

const int RPM_PIN=3;
volatile int rpm                = 0;    // Тахометр
volatile int rpm_tik            = 0;    // Импуслы тахометра

void rpm_count(){
  rpm_tik++;
}

void SensorData(){
  rpm = rpm_tik;
  rpm_tik = 0;
}

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(RPM_PIN,INPUT);
   attachInterrupt(RPM_PIN,  rpm_count,  RISING);
   Timer3.attachInterrupt(SensorData);
   Timer3.start(1000000);
}

void loop(){
    Serial.println(rpm/2*60);
    delay(500);
}
```

на малых оборотах двигателя все соответствует истине. Но при увеличении оборотов показания начинают завышаться. Так при оборотах 5000-5500 (примерное значение, ибо прибор аналоговый) - получаю значение 6600 и выше. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4):

Заменил вызов прерывания на:

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RPM_PIN), rpm_count,  RISING);
```

вместо

```
attachInterrupt(RPM_PIN, rpm_count,  RISING);
```

Все заработало правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Слишком много вариантов, начиная от программных глюков (хотя на это не похоже) и заканчивая наводками от системы зажигания.

Берите осциллограф, изучайте форму входного сигнала. Тут хватит и осциллографа из звуковой карты.

Берите также генератор и давайте вашему тахометру тестовые сигналы.

Comment: Входной сигнал формируется связкой датчик холла-оптопара. Форма - ровный меандр. Наводка от зажигания - не возможна. Экранированный кабель, проходит в другом месте. даже не пересекается. Именно что-то программное. Но понять не могу. Причем если значение было бы меньше - тут вопросов нет. Где то пропуски импульсов. А если больше .... Неправильно таймер работает?

Comment: @Stalker1204 может, аналоговый прибор брешет? Дайте заведомо известный сигнал с генератора.

Comment: Вечером, конечно, попробую, но боюсь если мой движок (5.7 л. 8 цилиндров, карбюратор) раскрутить хотя бы до 5500 оборотов он развалится :)

Comment: @Stalker1204 да не движком надо давать сигнал, а электронным генератором тестовых сигналов. Для тахометра и звуковой карты хватит.

Comment: Суть не в том. То был сарказм. Подал с осциллографа тестовый сигнал в 5кГц. Программа показывает 6600. Вот и возврат к вопросу.

Comment: @Stalker1204 прозреваю, что кривокосая ардуина пропускает прерывания от таймера, которые обнуляют счетчик тиков.